# HTML Header Dropdown not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue where my dropdown menu is not working. Like sometimes when I change something in my css or html and refresh the page it will work once but then never again. Can't for the life of me figure out why. I'm referring to the ul with the class of nav navbar-nav pull-right.

Hopefully pick the brains of you guys for some assistance.

Here is the code for my page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Website Title & Description for Search Engine purposes -->
    <title></title>
    <meta name="Richmond Movie Club" content="">

    <!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="includes/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="includes/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Include Modernizr in the head, before any other Javascript -->
    <script src="includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- end responsive-dropdown -->

            <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">RichmondMC</a>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="movieDatabase.php">Movie Database</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ratings.php">Ratings</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- end navbar-nav -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account <strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#registerModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Register New User</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> Sign In</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Sign Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- end dropdown-menu -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- end dropdown -->
                </ul>
                <!-- end myAccount-dropdown -->
            </div>
            <!-- end nav-collapse -->
            
        </div>
        <!-- end container -->
    </div>
    <!-- end navbar -->


    <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>

                            <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> New User Registration </h4>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end modal-header -->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h5>Enter the New Members details including username/password to complete registration</h5><br>

                            <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="username" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Username:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Password:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="firstName" class="col-lg-4 control-label">First Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lastName" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Last Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="emailAddress" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Email Address:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="phoneNumber" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Phone Number:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" id="alertMe">Submit</button><br>
                            </form>
                            <!-- end form -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- end modal-body -->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="alert alert-success alert-block fade in" id="successAlert">
                                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4>Success!</h4>
                                <p>New user registered successfully</p>
                            </div><!-- end alert -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- end modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- end modal -->



    <!-- All Javascript at the bottom of the page for faster page loading -->

    <!-- First try for the online version of jQuery-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- If no online access, fallback to our hardcoded version of jQuery -->
    <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="includes/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="includes/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*EDIT*

Forgot to include that these are .php files.
This is my header.php and I include it into all my pages with a
    `<?php include "header.php" ?>`
 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine in the below snippet. There must be some problem in your custom css or js file which is coming in the way of the dropdown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Website Title & Description for Search Engine purposes -->
    <title></title>
    <meta name="Richmond Movie Club" content="">

    <!-- Mobile viewport optimized -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="includes/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="includes/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Include Modernizr in the head, before any other Javascript -->
    <script src="includes/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- end responsive-dropdown -->

            <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">RichmondMC</a>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="movieDatabase.php">Movie Database</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ratings.php">Ratings</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- end navbar-nav -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account <strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#registerModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Register New User</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span> Sign In</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Sign Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- end dropdown-menu -->
                    </li>
                    <!-- end dropdown -->
                </ul>
                <!-- end myAccount-dropdown -->
            </div>
            <!-- end nav-collapse -->
            
        </div>
        <!-- end container -->
    </div>
    <!-- end navbar -->


    <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>

                            <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> New User Registration </h4>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end modal-header -->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h5>Enter the New Members details including username/password to complete registration</h5><br>

                            <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="username" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Username:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Password:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="firstName" class="col-lg-4 control-label">First Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lastName" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Last Name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="emailAddress" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Email Address:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="phoneNumber" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Phone Number:</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" id="alertMe">Submit</button><br>
                            </form>
                            <!-- end form -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- end modal-body -->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="alert alert-success alert-block fade in" id="successAlert">
                                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4>Success!</h4>
                                <p>New user registered successfully</p>
                            </div><!-- end alert -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- end modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!-- end modal -->



    <!-- All Javascript at the bottom of the page for faster page loading -->

    <!-- First try for the online version of jQuery-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- If no online access, fallback to our hardcoded version of jQuery -->
    <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="includes/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="includes/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't add the bootstrap css and js in the header.php. Rather try to include it in every page. Did you tried this?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference.
I have discovered that if I switch between pages using nav links in the nav bar and click the dropdown it will work for the 1st click only. But soon as I click off of the dropdown and try to click again the dropdown will not appear

Comment: omg so obvious haha! Of course I dont need to include all those files when I am including it into the main pages. Removed all the css, js and javascript cdn's now its working perfect. Legend!